# React-router update blocking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react-router set up, clicking on most of my links work.  When I click on a link with an ID, first one works, then on the second... URL gets updated, but not the component.

I found this link that should explain the problem and solution, but it's just not clear to me what the solution is. Can anyone help me understand what I'm to do?

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

Comment: I am not using PureComponents anywhere.  I am not using redux.

Comment: how about custom `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: There can be many reasons why it is not updating. It's hard to tell without looking at the source code. Is it possible for your to post the source code demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using componentDidMount...

Is that an issue for some reason?